# Event handler is removed by GC when subscribed to external event

Tags: c#, .net, events, garbage-collection, external

For work, I have to subscribe to an external event and handle it when it comes by. I have no problem doing all that but I noticed that after the first GC pass, the event handler I added seemingly gets removed. I won't be able to receive the next event after the collection.

If I manually trigger the GC then remove and add the handler, I will properly receive the next event.

I tried using KeepAlive and SuppressFinalize from the GC to no avail. I also tried to add the handler as a lambda, but it still gets removed after the first garbage collection.

example code (pseudo, for reference only)

```
private externalLibrary.Server server = new Server();

private externalLibrary.DataHandler handler; //delegate is assigned in constructor

public bool Subscribe(){

    //...
   server.Data.Received += handler;

}
```

With this setup, I receive events until the first GC.

My ugly workaround looks like this:

```
ResetHandler(){

    server.Data.Received -= handler;//It seems to already be removed by GC but better be safe than sorry

    server.Data.Received += handler;

}
```

And in the code when I finished my processing of the event, I do:

```
GC.Collect;

ResetHandler();
```

This allows me to circumvent the problem. I would like to find a better solution or know what I am doing wrong.

Please note that this is my very first question here.

Thank you for your input.

Comment: GC does no such thing; whatever is happening: it isn't GC. If this was me, I would start by looking in reflector (or similar) to see what the external code is doing; is it, for example, doing either 1) resetting the event subscriptions on event invoke (which is ... unusual), or 2) changing the `server.Data` object occasionally, with the old one becoming unreachable, with the expectation that you somehow know to resubscribe via the new `server.Data` instance (either 1 or 2 would explain why your resubscribing hack fixes the perceived issue)

Comment: (it may be helpful if you can indicate what `server.Data` actually is here; someone may be directly familiar with that utility)

Comment: If it's not doing one of the things Marc mentioned then it could be somehow storing the data in an unmanaged location (which would be...odd).  If that's the case, you need to figure out how to keep it rooted, not how to re-add the handler when it gets removed.

Comment: What strongly leads me to believe GC is involved is that if I trigger the collection manually without calling the reset handler method, I do not receive further events. If I do not call for GC myself, I will stop receiving events after the first regular collection (I confirmed it). I will take a look at the leads you provided me. Thanks!

Comment: Right now I can only say that Data is an interface provided by the externalDll. I will try using reflector to see what is going on in there.

Comment: Suggestion: let's imagine that the `.Data` object is **not rooted by the service**, and that it is generated in the getter: capture and store `.Data` **once**, and keep hold of it, and never go via `server.Data` again. To test this, try: `bool isThisTheProblem = !ReferenceEquals(server.Data, server.Data);` (I would strongly suggest that this would be a very bad design choice by the implementor)

Comment: I just tested this and sadly it does not seem to be the problem. The reference is equal. This would have made sense though.

Comment: It doesn't sound like the getter for `Data` is creating a new instance of `Data`, but that doesn't mean that the value isn't being changed somewhere else, perhaps even in `Server` itself? Try storing the value of `server.Data` in a field on your `class`... maybe in the constructor or when you call `Subscribe`. That way your class is holding on to that reference, and see if the received event is handled properly.

Comment: I stored the data value just before subscribing. I then used the stored data throughout my code. It now seems to work as I can trigger the garbage collection and keep receiving events afterwards. I will still keep an eye on things and perform long winded tests but I thank you all very much.

Comment: So, `server.Data.Received` is some sort of weak collection, perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, it could very well be. That would be a reasonable explanation for what's going on.